# Linebreak in \titleformat

Tags: tikz-pgf, sectioning

```
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {\thesection}
  {0pt}
  {\tikz \fill [fill={rgb:black,1;white,4}] (0,0) rectangle (\linewidth,0.25);}
```

[image]

I used the above code to add a grey bar above the section title, but the section name cannot move to a new line. I tried to add `\\` and `\newline`, the problem still cannot be solved. How to make a new line in `\titleformat` ? thanks!

Comment: Please post a compilable document, not just fragments only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact `\newline` works well if you use it this way :

```
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\thesection}
{0pt}
{\tikz \fill [fill={rgb:black,1;white,4}] (0,0) rectangle (\linewidth,0.25);\newline \vspace{0.5pt}}
```

You can modify `\vspace` to set the height of the thing.

[image: Is this the result you wanted ?]

Answer (score 3):

You just have to use the `[display]` style optional argument of `\titleformat`.

On the other hand, you do not need to use `tkiz` for such a simple rule: the `\titlerule` command is provided by `titlesec` for such things.

As I didn't know if you want the rule between section number and section title, or on the same line as the title number, I provided both.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}%
\usepackage{titlesec}%
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example
\titleformat{\section}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\thesection}
{0pt}
{{\color{Silver! 80}\titlerule[0.25cm]}\vspace{0.5ex}}

\begin{document}

\section{Objectifs}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]